# sqlite database is not connecting

Tags: python, database, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to access data in the database but i cant connect to the database. If I try to add more data to the database using a different script I can access the database but with this I cant connect to the database

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('D:\PycharmProjects\tensortest\data.db')
with conn:
   pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM Data where Year=2018',conn,index_col='index')
```

OperationalError: unable to open database file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain combinations of backslash and character have a special meaning like e. g. `\t` is replaced by the tab character. Therefore use for the path either a raw string `r"C:\..."` to disable the backslash escape sequences or replace the backslashes by forward slashes (Windows can cope with that).

Comment: Thanks I had did that in the other file but forgot it here